# Invert the y axis in my 3D rotating menu (as3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I got the problem where I have made this 3D rotating menu. My code look like this.

```
import flash.events.Event;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    anim.rotationX += ((stage.mouseY - stage.stageHeight/2)-anim.rotationX*20) * 0.009;
    anim.rotationY += ((stage.mouseX - stage.stageWidth/4)-anim.rotationY*20)  * 0.009;
}
```

but I dont know how to make the y axis inverted, so the movieclip moves opposite at the y-axis

can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
anim.rotationY += ((stage.mouseX - stage.stageWidth/4)-anim.rotationY*20)  * 0.009;
```

To:

```
anim.rotationY -= ((stage.mouseX - stage.stageWidth/4)-anim.rotationY*20)  * 0.009;
```